# Multiple MapKit overlay colours from array

Tags: arrays, swift, mapkit, overlay, cloudkit

How do I make each bubble a different colour?

Here is my array of colours:

```
var tableColors = [UIColor(red: 220.0/255.0, green: 95.0/255.0,  blue: 19.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9),  // Rust
    UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 191.0/255.0, blue: 59.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9),  // Yellow
    UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 91.0/255.0,  blue: 51.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9),  // Red
    UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0,   green: 160.0/255.0, blue: 174.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9), // KAL
    UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0,   green: 121.0/255.0, blue: 95.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9),  // Green
    UIColor(red: 104.0/255.0, green: 68.0/255.0,  blue: 88.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9),  // Purple
    UIColor(red: 244.0/255.0, green: 97.0/255.0,  blue: 119.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9), // Pink
    UIColor(red: 1.0/255.0,   green: 116.0/255.0, blue: 200.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9), // Blue
    UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0,   green: 188.0/255.0, blue: 111.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9), // Light Green
    UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0,   green: 196.0/255.0, blue: 179.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9), // Aqua
    UIColor(red: 246.0/255.0, green: 50.0/255.0,  blue: 62.0/255.0, alpha: 0.9)] // Hot
```

Here is the code which creates the locations from CloudKit data.

```
func fetchBubble() {

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Collection", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))

    publicDB!.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in

        if error == nil {

            for collection in results! {

                let collectionLocation = collection.valueForKey("Location") as? CLLocation

                let collectionName = collection.valueForKey("Name") as! String

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailableForClass(CLCircularRegion.self) {

                        let intrepidLat: CLLocationDegrees =  (collectionLocation?.coordinate.latitude)!

                        let intrepidLong: CLLocationDegrees = (collectionLocation?.coordinate.longitude)!

                        let title = collectionName

                        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(intrepidLat, intrepidLong)

                        let regionRadius = 50.0

                        let region = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude,
                            longitude: coordinate.longitude), radius: regionRadius, identifier: title)

                        self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)

                        let restaurantAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()

                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(restaurantAnnotation)

                        restaurantAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate

                        let circle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: coordinate, radius: regionRadius)

                        self.mapView.addOverlay(circle)

                        self.numberOfObjectsInMyArray()

                    }

                    else {

                        print("System can't track regions")

                    }


                })

            }

        }

        else {

            print(error)

        }

    }

}
```

Then I draw the circles with the following code

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    let circleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)

    for index in 1...5 {

        circleRenderer.fillColor = self.tableColors[index + 1]

    }

    return circleRenderer

}
```

I've tried a few ways of looping through the colours but at the moment it is applying the same colour from the array to each of the bubbles.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the **rendererForOverlay** callout method you are setting same last color to all the circleRenderer. So instead of your code

```
for index in 1...5 {
    circleRenderer.fillColor = self.tableColors[index + 1]
}
```

replace with

```
circleRenderer.fillColor = self.randomTableColors()
```

And implement this method to give the random color as follow.

```
func randomTableColors() -> UIColor {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(tableColors.count)))
    return tableColors[randomIndex]
}
```